# Have an extra /directory/ in the results of a dynamic link on php page

Tags: php, xml, dynamic-linking

Here I am again. I hate to be a bother but here's another zinger.

I have a custom made shopping cart and have some dynamic links in the page that when served up in a browser will replace $name with the product name and $p with the procuct id number. I'm aiming for a link on the page like this: `http://www.something.com/buy/ProductName/382793/`

What I'm getting is `http://www.something.com/buy/ProductName/0/382793` and no trailing slash. Gotta have the slash.

The code looks like this: `<a title=\"View Product.\" href=\"http://www.something.com/buy/$name/$p/". $line["PID"]. "\">PRODUCT LINKO</a>`

You can see that I have $name and $p separated by a slash and a trailing slash at the end but it's not working. Any ideas ladies and gentlemen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tailing" slash at the end is escaping the double quote:

```
<a title=\"View Product.\" href=\"http://www.something.com/buy/$name/$p/". $line["PID"]. "/\">PRODUCT LINKO</a>
```

Should add the tailing slash as requested.

Comment: Well, how about that? Sometimes this stuff crosses my eyes.

Thanks a heap!